# How to make a ReadOnly Edit in a Python FMX GUI App

Tags: python, user-interface, firemonkey

I made an `Edit` on a `Form` using the [DelphiFMX Python Library](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python), but how do I make an `Edit` that is read-only?

The user should be able to read text in the Edit, but not be able to enter their own text.

Here's my current code to make an `Edit`:

```
self.edt = Edit(self)
self.edt.Parent = self
self.edt.Align = "Center"
self.edt.Width = 500
self.edt.Height = 100
self.edt.Text = "Hello World"
self.edt.StyledSettings = ""
self.edt.TextSettings.Font.Size = 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a `ReadOnly` boolean property that you can set to `True`:

```
self.edt.ReadOnly = True
```

But there's also an `Enabled` property that you can set to `False`:

```
self.edt.Enabled = False
```